# getting following error while deploying dashdb container on power platform- db2 warehouse

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, podman

[  OK  ] Started The entrypoint script for initializing the service.
[4227500.518576] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: Running 'Cgroup filesystem mount existence' test...
[4227500.528707] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: Running 'Platform sanity' test...
[4227500.794612] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: Running 'Docker storage driver' test...
[4227500.798941] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: Running 'SELinux status' test...
[4227501.057599] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: Running 'Root volume total-space' test...
[4227501.248627] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[4227501.249179] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: File "/usr/lib/nodes_helper.py", line 1246, in 
[4227501.249647] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: if not nodes_file_obj.initialize_nodes_file():
[4227501.250116] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: File "/usr/lib/nodes_helper.py", line 969, in initialize_nodes_file
[4227501.250595] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: nodes_from_nodesfile = self.get_nodes_from_old_nodesfile()
[4227501.251128] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: File "/usr/lib/nodes_helper.py", line 485, in get_nodes_from_old_nodesfile
[4227501.251657] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: return self._get_nodes_from_old_nodesfile(self.nodes_old_filename)
[4227501.252101] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: File "/usr/lib/nodes_helper.py", line 469, in _get_nodes_from_old_nodesfile
[4227501.252545] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: unicode(self._get_node_ip_from_nodesfile(line), 'utf-8')))
[4227501.252996] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: File "/usr/lib/nodes_helper.py", line 452, in _get_node_ip_from_nodesfile
[4227501.253440] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: return line.strip().split('=')[1].split(':')[1]
[4227501.253885] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: IndexError: list index out of range
[4227506.461585] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
[4227506.465628] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: FATAL RUNTIME ERROR DETECTED
[4227506.469829] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
[4227506.473835] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: Dumping system configuration details to help diagnose the problem
[4227506.715838] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: Running 'Docker storage driver' test...
[4227512.553657] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: * JSON CONFIG FILE: /mnt/blumeta0/options.json
[4227512.554124] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: An error was detected trying to parse the JSON configuration file
[4227512.554470] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: * ERROR:
[4227512.589790] start_dashDB_local.sh[212]: Generation of diagnostic information complete; stopping deployment of container immediately

Comment: I am executing command while spinning the dashdb container as     podman run -d -it --privileged=true --net=host --name=Db2wh -e DISABLE_SPARK=NO -e TABLE_ORG=ROW  -v /stage01:/mnt/blumeta0 -v /data01:/mnt/bludata0 -v /local01:/local01 -v /data04:/data04 -v /data03:/data03 -v /data02:/data02 -v /local02:/local02 -v /local03:/local03 -v /local04:/local04 -v /stage02:/stage02 -v /stage03:/stage03 -v /stage04:/stage04 icr.io/obs/hdm/db2wh_ee:v11.5.6.0-db2wh-ppcle
fe4c99b1b69846cb87b860d3b2ecb1588d70fc7f28965273c1abd7acf2f9f99e

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.